# Consuming SOAP with WCF: Receiving the reply body as raw XML

Tags: .net, wcf, soap

I'm writing a client for a third party SOAP service using a provided WSDL file. The default way to do this with WCF is to generate local proxy classes using svcutil and have WCF automatically deserialize replies to service calls into proxy objects.

However - since I already have established code that works well with XML and XPath for my purposes, I'm not intersted in using the proxy objects and would rather just receive the body in it's original form instead of having to re-serialize them. On the other hand I don't want the hassle of composing the SOAP requests myself and would like WCF to keep handling it.

I know that the /importXmlTypes flag for svcutil will almost get me there with just the top level reply objects with an array of XmlNode in them but optimally I would like

```
XmlDocument SomeServiceMethod(...)
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using `XmlElement` (instead of `XmlDocument`)? That should work. `XElement` should work as well.

Comment: Using XmlElement captured only the first element in the body. Using XmlElement[] oddly enough didn't capture anything and using XmlNode[] ultimately works (as suggested by a WCF error message) and is good enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do this but it's not really nice. You can create a message inspector and attach it to your proxy (with the [`IClientMessageInspector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx)). Sample: [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx).
So you can intercept the reply in it's bare form, but deserialization will still occur by the time the response reaches the proxy.

However, think about how will this work. You have your proxy which can already do the job, but you work around this **only** for replies (responses) which you parse manually.

Also, think about what happens when the service is updated/changed. You have to change your parsing code instead of just updating your proxy and then use the updated contracts.

Anyway, [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx#S6) some extra reading about custom WCF behaviors.

Comment: Yes, I know about inspectors and as you say I want to avoid unnecessary deserialization (and it's a bit ugly anyway).

If by do the job you mean give me convenient access to the data I'm getting, then yes it does the job. But ultimately my job is to map and store this data into my system. For the mapping bit I get a thorough specification defined by XPaths and available in a convenient format. For this we have tools that can automate a lot of the work and these tools are based on using xml and XPath. 

Also the replies are all that matters, the requests are simple requests for data.